# Comparison of diffusion time - theoretical value vs computed

Tags: pde, matlab, numerics, diffusion

This is a follow up to my [previous post](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34071/computation-of-diffusion-time/34076#34076)

I've been trying to compare the diffusion time obtained from theoretical
derivation(answered in my previous post) and what is obtained computationally, for a 1D diffusion equation.

Theoretically, the diffusion time is given by

$$t_D = \frac{l^2}{2D}$$
Calculating $t_D$ , l = 5 nm and D = 500 $nm^2/min$ gives  $t_D$ = 0.025 min.

The following is the MATLAB code that simulates 1D diffusion system using pdepe solver.

```
function sol=so()
format short
global D nnode init_co find_index
m = 0;
xend = 5; 
D = 500; 
x = 0:1:xend;
find_index  = 0:1:xend;
t = 0:0.00001:0.5;
init_co = 1*ones(length(x),1);
nnode = length(x);
sol = pdepe(m,@pdefun,@icfun,@bcfun,x,t)
plot(t,sol)
function [g,f,s] = pdefun(x,t,c,DcDx)
g = 1;
f = D*DcDx;
s = 0;
end

function c0 = icfun(x)
c0 = init_co(find(find_index==x));
end

function [pl,ql,pr,qr] = bcfun(xl,cl,xr,cr,t)
% Dirichlet at left (concentration at left boundary = 2, Neumann at right(dC/dx = 0)
    pl = cl - 3;
    ql = 0;
    pr = 0;
    qr = 1;
end
end
```

Result:
[image]
From the plot of C vs time, all the curves reach a steady-state at 0.1 min.

Could someone explain why there is a difference in what is computed theoretically and computationally? Is it appropriate to make this comparison?

Comment: “All curves reach a steady state at 0.1”.  That’s simply not true.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson I think OP is confused about the graph due to the fact that concentration and time axes are flipped in this plot.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Thanks for pointing out. The labels are wrong.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Please find the updated plot

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with the labels.  It still stands.  The curves exponentially approach the steady state.  They certainly do not reach it at 0.1.

Comment: Diffusion time $t_D~L^2/D$ is a characteristic time scale. $t_s=f t_D$ is associated with the time the steady state was established, where the dimensionless function $f$ depends on the initial data. For example, if the initial data satisfy equation $\nabla.(D\nabla c)=0$, then $f$ is close to zero (depends on the numerical method).

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thank you, I understand what you are saying. Is there a better way to make such comparisons between theoretical and computational predictions?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Thanks a lot for the explanation. Since the values are different by an order of magnitude, I am a little perplexed

Comment: I think what you really need is to understand what "diffusion time" means.  This is not a computational question at all; it's a mathematical definition.  You seem to interepret it as "the time at which a plot of the solution will look like it is very close to the steady state", but that's too imprecise to be a mathematical definition.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thanks a lot for the response. Computationally, I intend to check for the time that a substance takes to diffuse through a length L(length of the domain). I'm not sure if it would be appropriate to call it as diffusional residence time . Any suggestions on how such a quantity can be computed?

Comment: "I intend to check for the time that a substance takes to diffuse through a length L" -- Again, you need a precise definition first.  Checking when the graph of the value looks close to the steady state is too imprecise for any kind of mathematical or scientific work.  A useful definition would be something like "the time at which the concentration at a distance L reaches 50% of the concentration at the point of origin".  The 50% is not important, but you need something precisely measurable.

Comment: I think @DavidKetcheson is right here. For that 50%, I suggest to replace it with $100 \times (1-e^{-1})$%, which is approximately 63%. It comes from the fact that most popular kinetics theory to describe a diffusion is exponential kinetics or change of concentration with respect to time must be: $C(t) = C_{\infty} (1-\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau}))$, where $C_{\infty}$ is your concentration at $t = \infty$ and $\tau$ is your relaxation time or kinetics parameter that is directly related to diffusion coefficient. Now, when you want to know when system will reach steady state: $t = \tau$.

Comment: You can find that $\tau$ easily and that time scale gives you a solid definition of diffusion time.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer similar to `C(t) = C_{\infty} (1-\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau}))` that describes the exponential kinetics of diffusion is there a way to determine the kinetic parameter that can be related to velocity for studying convection.Please let me know if I have to post this question in a new thread

Comment: @Natasha Yes, in fact there is one dimensionless parameter called Peclet number: $$Pe = \frac{2vR}{D}$$ Where $v$ is your velocity, $R$ is the radius of the pipe, and $D$ is the diffusion coefficient. It gives you a quantitative measure about how strong are convection fluxes in comparison to diffusive fluxes. But, if you are looking for a **model** similar to exponential kinetics model to describe mass transport with convection mechanism, you need to be more specific about your geometry, stationary or time-dependency of your study, and your boundary conditions, then I could help you.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Thank you, I've opened a new thread [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/comparison-of-convection-time-theoretical-value-vs-computed)