# Comparison of convection time - theoretical value vs computed

Tags: pde, numerics, advection-diffusion, advection

This is a follow up to my previous post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34169/comparison-of-diffusion-time-theoretical-value-vs-computed),

I'm solving for convection in 1D

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = - v\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}$$

The discretization of the above equation is presented using a backward difference formula,
$$\frac{d C}{dt} = -v \frac{C_{i} - C_{i-1}}{\Delta x}$$

The boundary condition is imposed at the left end of the domain (i.e inlet)

$$\frac{d C}{dt}_{i=1} = -v \frac{C_{i} - C_{0}}{\Delta x}$$

and $C_0$ is specified
for observing the transient change in C over a time span 
[0 tend].

Similar to the exponential kinetics

$C(t) = C_{\infty} (1-\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau}))$

[presented](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/34169/comparison-of-diffusion-time-theoretical-value-vs-computed) for describing mass transport with diffusion mechanism, I'd to know if a similar expression can be derived for describing convection.

Comment: The exact solution is simply translation of the initial data to the right at speed $v$.  So yes, you can easily determine exactly how long it will take a signal to reach any given point.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson In fact, any given function in the form of $C(x,t) = f(x-vt)$ satisfies that equation. Still, you are confused cause you are trying to evaluate your governing equation at the inlet node, which is not correct.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer  I'd to know if an expression similar to exponential kinetics can be derived for describing convection

Comment: @Natasha The answer is **no**, unless you provide more information.

Comment: @AloneProgrammer Thanks a lot for the response. By more information do you mean boundary conditions? It's Dirichlet at the inlet. Please let me know if you are looking for other information.